# replacing a special character in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that '?' instead of 'NaN' for missing values. I could have gone through each column using replace but the only problem is I have 22 columns. I am trying to create a loop do it effectively but I am getting wrong. Here is what I am doing:

```
 for col in adult.columns:
      if adult[col]=='?':
         adult[col]=adult[col].str.replace('?', 'NaN')
```

The plan is to use the 'NaN' then use the **fillna** function or to drop them with **dropna**. The second problem is that not all the columns are categorical so the *str* function is also wrong. How can I easily deal with this situation?

Comment: why can't you do `adult.replace('?', np.nan)`? This would replace every `'?'` with `NaN` in your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reading the data from a `.csv` or `.xlsx` file you can use the `na_values` parameter:

```
adult = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', na_values=['?'])
```

Otherwise do what @MasonCaiby said and use `adult.replace('?', float('nan'))`

Comment: I did nit know that this worked as well . I though it was only for columns or series. Thanks